# Node.js + Socket.io localhost over lan

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

As I am rather new to node.js I've stumbled upon a problem. If I try to share a chat app over LAN via ip address it's impossible to start handshake, because it requests it from localhost instead of ip address.

Is there a way to change this parameter?

Picture of my problem:

[image]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Ho do you add your socket.io.js script?

You should insert it like this:

`<script src="/socket/socket.io.js"></script>`

Comment: Well, mine is actually <script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> because that's the name of my folder. It works perfect in localhost, but if I try it on a different machine in LAN it doesn't anymore.

Comment: ok, and how do you connect to your server?

io.connect("http://123.456.789.123");

Answer (score 0):

Assume that your host node.js ip address is 192.168.0.2 . All you have to do is just try to access this via a web browser:

```
http://192.168.0.2/socket.io/socket.io.js
```

If you can see some javascript there, your network between machine is connected. In your client machine, you have to code as:

```
<script src="http://192.168.0.2/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

If it works, that's it. If it does not work, there maybe some issue with your network setting. You should try to ping to another machine and have it success first then try again.

Comment: It doesn't work, if I do '<script src="http://192.168.0.2/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>' it doesn't start even in localhost, if I add '<script src="http://192.168.0.2:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>' it works but still the same issue with localhost. Can't share it out.

Comment: so, you have opened socket.io on 8080 port. Try access http://192.168.0.2:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js in your client machine's web browser. If it's not working, you gotta check the network connection between each machine.